# C getaddrinfo() not resolving name

Tags: c, sockets, dns, getaddrinfo

I have a program (written in C) that uses `getaddrinfo()` and its first parameter is the host name that I want it to get address information about, let's say it is "domain".  In my `/etc/hosts` file on the same machine I can see that "domain" is supposed to resolve to 192.168.1.200.  When I run the program it hangs on this call every time and cannot get the address information.  However, if I replace "domain" with the actual IP Address, it works just fine.

By the way, this problem didn't exist a week or so ago, it is a new problem that has suddenly reared it's ugly head.  I am fairly certain that something must have been done to this machine in the last week, and I have attempted to verify this with our other staff, but they also have no idea why this would occur.

So, my question is, does anyone out there have any idea what this would suddenly be occurring?  What can I check to verify that it is configured how it should be?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you post a code sample?

Comment: Can command-line tools such as `ping` resolve the same names correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Linux? My guess is that you've messed up something with the `libnss` mess glibc uses to route all its name lookups (hostnames, usernames, group names, etc.), perhaps by a botched glibc upgrade. Try running your program with `strace` and see if it's trying (and failing) to open `libnss_*` files. Also look in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to make sure the `hosts:` line reads `hosts: files dns`. `man nsswitch.conf` could be helpful.

Comment: Yes sorry, we are using Linux (Gentoo) and it is possibly a botched glibc upgrade problem, I will look into that.  Thank you.

Comment: Turns out I was making a big assumption DOH!  I wrote a short little program using the function in question and worked no problem!  After some more searching and debugging, I found it was a problem with the data it was getting back from the socket connection I was making.  Sorry for the trouble, but thanks for the help.